# adding images to a canvas in a for loop only shows last image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, game-engine

I am trying to font images from a sprite sheet to a canvas from a for loop. i have made a simple class called `Font` to load a font spritesheet. within the class i have a function called `drawChar(posX, posY)` after declaring a new font object inside my loop i call `font.drawChar(posX, posY);` only the last image seems to appear but it is in the correct location. here is my code

**index.html**

```js
    var screenbuffer = [
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],


    ];
    
    const ctx = setupCanvas(document.getElementById("canvas"));

    const font = new Font('img/IBM8x16_NoPadding_extended.png')

    window.onload = () => {

        loadScreen(32, 64, screenbuffer);

        //ctx.drawImage(font.fontImage, 10, 10);
    }

    //const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");


function setupCanvas(canvas) {
  // Get the device pixel ratio, falling back to 1.
  var dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
  // Get the size of the canvas in CSS pixels.
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  // Give the canvas pixel dimensions of their CSS
  // size * the device pixel ratio.
  canvas.width = rect.width * dpr;
  canvas.height = rect.height * dpr;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  // Scale all drawing operations by the dpr, so you
  // don't have to worry about the difference.
  ctx.scale(dpr, dpr);
  return ctx;
}

    



function loadScreen(resX, resY, screen){

    var drawPosX = 0;
    var drawPosY = 0;
    var tilesizeX = 32;
    var tilesizeY = 64;
    for(var i = 0; i < screen.length; i++) {
        var screenLine = screen[i];
        for(var j = 0; j < screenLine.length; j++) {
            drawPosX = j;
            drawPosY = i;
            font.drawChar(drawPosX * tilesizeX, drawPosY * tilesizeY)
            
        }
    }
}
```

**font.js**

```js
class Font{
    constructor(src, tilesizeX, tilesizeY){
        this.fontImage = new Image();
        this.fontImage.src = src;
        //this.fontImage.onload = this.drawChar();
    }

    drawChar(posX, posY){
        console.log(posX, posY)
        // draw color
        ctx.fillStyle = "#00F";
        ctx.fillRect(posX, posY, 32, 64);

        // set composite mode
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";

        // draw image
        ctx.drawImage(this.fontImage, 8, 0, 8 , 16 , posX, posY, 32, 64);
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";

    }
}
```

what could I be doing wrong? the only thing I can think of is maybe it has something to do with `ctx.globalCompositeOperation` but I am still uncertain.

Comment: _"maybe it has something to do with `ctx.globalCompositeOperation`"_ Did you try to change `destination-in` to `source-over`, to rule that out or confirm your doubts?

Comment: if i dont have the `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";` line at the end nothing shows at all.

Comment: I am not talking about that line

Comment: ok so changing the first line to be `source-over` shows all of the images. but my reason for using `destination-in` was to color the image blue. is there any workaround?

Comment: Ok, not easy to say without being able to play with an example that reproduces the issue. Maybe (and it's a big "maybe") you will need to use a temporary canvas to draw each letter, and "paste" this one-char canvas onto the other one on every iteration

Comment: The source X and source Y of your draw image call is constant. You should make it multiply by the tile index. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage